# Frequent Hanging when an invalid date is mistakenly entered by app users

Tags: visual-foxpro

I run into this problem quite a lot with users of our big HR database application, written in Visual FoxPro 6.0 but presently running in Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP1. If a user mistakenly enters a date that is not valid (say with month number 14 or day number 35), the system just hangs and the task must be killed with the Windows Task Manager (we are using Windows 7 Professional). Is there a way of handling this from the app? Also, since moving to the VFP 9.0 upgrade, the app hangs a lot, especially if users click at some places on the screen unintentionally. They have to be frequently calling up the Windows Task Manager to kill the task and then resume again, with attendant data losses and frustrations. This never happened when we were using Visual FoxPro 6.0. Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem? Thanks. ZaTones

Comment: Are you using modal windows? And if so, do those modal windows have ActiveX controls in them?

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, did the change to VFP 9 also change the application to use a top-level form or at least, adding SCREEN=OFF to the config.fpw. The problem is that the automatic messages that tell you about this kind of error are showing up in the main VFP window instead of something visible.

To test this theory, hit spacebar when the app seems hung and see whether it comes alive. (Not 100% sure that'll work to unfreeze, though.)

The answer is to either live in the VFP workspace (that is, without SCREEN=OFF) or not rely on the automatic messages for bad dates. SET NOTIFY OFF and handle it yourself.

Tamar